# Line Spacing of Text in QML TextArea

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I am unable to find how to implement line-Height in QML TextArea.

Since in Text item we have the property of `line-height` and `lineHeightMode` and suppose I have line-height of 22px then how to implement it in TextArea item which is further present in a Rectangle of fixed height and width (78 and 288 resp.).

Comment: Is this different from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67536371/line-height-of-text-in-textarea-in-qml)?

Comment: @JarMan No this is same as the previous one . Since the previous one has the code and this one do not ..so i thought anyone can be used which you guys find suitable . But please try to solve this issue . I am badly stuck at this point